# Keyboard and trackpad not working after logic board upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, nvram

I had an issue with RAM on my old logic board of a 2011 MacBook Air. I decided to replace the old logic board with a more recent i7 2017 logic board. I got to get all running but the keyboard and the trackpad. Unfortunately with no keyboard I can’t power up the laptop, but that’s not the biggest issue as far I keep it always on. I tried to reset nvram through terminal but no way, I get error clearing firmware variables (iokit/common) not permitted.
Does anybody have any clue why keyboard is not responding at all? Any suggestions on how to fix it?
I am currently using a Bluetooth keyboard and a usb mouse but it’s not the same as being able to use the built-in ones.
Together with the the logic board I replaced the I/O, hard drive, airport but all the rest fitted perfectly. And yes, I did connect the keyboard and the trackpad with the logic board.
Thank you in advance for any help. It will be very much appreciated. I’m kind of stuck here.